# ruby memory leak Gdk::PixbufLoader

Tags: ruby, memory-leaks, gtk2, gdk

So I'm beginning to wonder how leaky the gnome2 libraries for ruby1.8.6 are.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'gtk2'
while true
   sleep 0.1
   pixbuf = Gdk::PixbufLoader.new
   pixbuf = nil
end
```

this leaks about 16kb/sec according to `watch -n 1 ps -o rss -p <process id>`

This is compounded if you start trying to write a chunk of large chunks of image data to it using `pixbuf.last_write img_data`

Any ideas how to get around this (and the second issue)? I need to update image data within my code but it seems like anything that ends up using a pixbuf leaks like a sieve.